# Update using substring inside case in postgress

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I am trying to update this table in my database

```
update  f4211_mod
set "Channel"=case
        when substring(a."SHURRF",1,1) in ('P','2','4','5','7') then 'Showroom'
        when substring(a."SHURRF",1,1) in ('6') then 'Binnendienst'
        when substring(a."SHRCD") in ('A','B') then 'Express'
        when substring(a."SHIR01") in ('B2B','EDI','ICM','PTC','WBXML') then 'E-commerce'
        else "Channel" = 'Binnendienst'
        end
        from f4211_join as a
```

But I am getting this error

```
ERROR:  function substring(character varying) does not exist
LINE 5:   when substring(a."SHRCD") in ('A','B') then 'Express'
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 186
```

Please fix this

Comment: `Please fix this` ... please tell us what the join condition is between the 2 tables.

Comment: there is no join, you can remove that a too

Comment: Then why is there a `FROM` clause?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question, those column "SHURRF" AND OTHER COLUMN ARE FROM F4211_JOIN AND i m updating this table f4211_mod from that table

Comment: Your usage of the SUBSTRING function is incorrect. Did you read the documentation? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-string.html

Comment: @JonasMetzler I tried using  when substring(a."SHURRF" from 1 for 1) in ('P','2','4','5','7') then 'Showroom'
  and i got this error (ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "Showroom") but my column is varchar(30)

Comment: The error message informs that the part substring(a."SHRCD") is incorrect and the documentation explains why. So you need to fix this part.

Comment: @JonasMetzler ya I got that, that's why i tried by putting comment on other 3 statment and tried on 1st only and i got (ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "Showroom") but my column is varchar(30)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is clear from the error message that there is no version of substring function which accepts a string alone as parameter `substring(string)`. You need to pass the `starting position` or `starting position and number of characters to be extracted` as parameters in the substring function as you are doing in the previous lines.
You might like to check different overloaded versions of the substring function [here](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/substring-function.php) or in the attached image and use anyone from those for your requirement.[Different versions of substring function in postgres 9.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPnhg.png)

Comment: I tried using when substring(a."SHURRF" from 1 for 1) in ('P','2','4','5','7') then 'Showroom' and i got this error (ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "Showroom") but my column is varchar(30)

Comment: please try this -

UPDATE 
  f4211_mod 
SET 
  Channel = CASE WHEN substring(a.SHURRF FROM 1 FOR 1) IN ('P', '2', '4', '5', '7') THEN 'Showroom' ELSE 'Binnendienst' END 
FROM 
  f4211_join as a;

Add the other `cases` in the SQL as needed